# Calling a stored procedure that takes 2 parameters from inside a stored procedure that takes 1 parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure `usp_gethomedata(<current year>)` that takes only current year (2012) as parameter and displays data for `01-01-2012` to current date of 2012 i.e 26-11-2012.

I have another stored procedure that shows similar data in `usp_gethomedata(<start date>, <end date>)` that takes 2 parameter start and end date ranges from `01-01-1900` to `26-11-2012`.

Now, I am not sure how to call the second stored procedure from inside the 1st one so that it display me data for  `01-01-2012` to  `26-11-2012` provided I have to keep in mind.. that while calling the 1st procedure I can supply only the 2012 i.e the current year as a parameter from my asp .net application.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot create overloaded stored procedure. One will override the other. Though Overloaded function is possible. So, change the inner stored procedure to some different name or the vice versa (i.e. outer stored procedure). Here is an example that will simulate your situation.

-- **Outer stored procedure**

```
USE [Test]
GO

-- exec [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData] 2012
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[USP_GetHomeData]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(
    @Year INT
)
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @startDate DATETIME='1/1/' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4))  -- mm/dd/yyyy
        DECLARE @endDate DATETIME=GETDATE() -- mm/dd/yyyy

        SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(Day,Number,@startDate) 
        FROM  master..spt_values  WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE Type='P'
        AND DATEADD(day,Number,@startDate) <= @endDate

        exec [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData_Inner] '1/1/1900', @endDate
END
```

-- **Inner stored procedure**

```
USE [Test]
GO

-- exec [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData_Inner] '1/1/1900', '11/25/2012'
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[USP_GetHomeData_Inner]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData_Inner]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetHomeData_Inner] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(
    @startDate DATETIME
    ,@endDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN

        ;WITH Calender AS 
        (
            SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
            WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
        )
        SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25) 
        FROM Calender WITH(NOLOCK)
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
END
```

The result (partial) is as under

[image]

Hope this helps.